# Sympy derivation

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, derivative

I'm working with EPR spectrums and using Dyson function to fit experimental data.

```
def dyson(x, B_0, delta_B, alpha):
  return (((delta_B + alpha*(x - B_0))/(4*(x - B_0)**2 + delta_B**2)) 
  + ((delta_B - alpha*(x + B_0))/(4*(x + B_0)**2 + delta_B**2)))
```

I get its derivative using Sympy:

```
x = Symbol('x')
delta_B = Symbol('delta_B')
B_0 = Symbol('B_0')
alpha = Symbol('alpha')
y = (((delta_B + alpha*(x - B_0))/(4*(x - B_0)**2 + delta_B**2)) 
  + ((delta_B - alpha*(x + B_0))/(4*(x + B_0)**2 + delta_B**2)))
der_dyson = lambdify((x, delta_B, B_0, alpha), y.diff(x))
```

However, result doesn't match calculations using finite differences method:

```
def der_dyson_(x, B_0, delta_B, alpha, h=1):
  return (dyson(x + h, B_0, delta_B, alpha) - dyson(x - h, B_0, delta_B, alpha))/(2*h)
fig_test, ax_test = plt.subplots()
x_test = np.linspace(-600, 600, 10000)
ax_test.plot(x_test, der_dyson_(x_test, 200, 250, 0.5, h=0.12), label='finite diff')
ax_test.plot(x_test, der_dyson(x_test, 200, 250, 0.5), label='Sympy')
ax_test.legend()
```

[image: plots of derivatives]

I checked out expression for derivative that Sympy gives and it seems to be correct so I can't figure out what is the problem. In the article where Dyson function defined, author adds graph of Dyson derivative which is of the form corresponding to my finite differences computation.

[image: derivative in original article]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the order of parameters is incorrect:

```
der_dyson = lambdify((x, delta_B, B_0, alpha), y.diff(x))
```

It should correspond to the order in `dyson`:

```py
def dyson(x, B_0, delta_B, alpha):
    ...

def get_dyson_deriv():
    x = Symbol('x')
    delta_B = Symbol('delta_B')
    B_0 = Symbol('B_0')
    alpha = Symbol('alpha')
    y = dyson(x, B_0, delta_B, alpha)
    # NOTE order of parameters in the tuple here:
    return lambdify((x, B_0, delta_B, alpha), y.diff(x))

der_dyson = get_dyson_deriv()
```

With this change, the two graphs become nearly identical, even with `h=0.12`.

Also note that you don't need to retype the expression of `dyson` when computing the derivative. Simply pass the `Symbol`s directly to the `dyson` function.